# Snapdragon neural processing- SNPE

Tags: android, input, mobile, conv-neural-network, snpe

I am quite new to this platform so please be kind if my question is stupid. Currently I am trying to integrate a deep learning model by using SNPE to detect human pose. The architecture of the model is as following:

Input -> CNN layers -> seperate to two different set of CNN -- > 2 different output layers

So, basically my network is stated from an input data and then genertates two different outputs (output1 and output2), but when I try to execute the network in SNPE, It seems like only have information about the output2 layer. Do any of you has any idea about this situation and is it possipole for me to look for the output of output1. Thank you all in Advance!.

Comment: I have exactly this problem. Thanks so much for asking the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have successfully converted the model to DLC and are trying to run the network with snpe-net-run tool. For getting multiple outputs, while running snpe-net-run you need to specify the output layers (in addition to input) in the file that is given to --input_list argument.
Let's assume *outputlayer1* and *outputlayer2* are the names of 2 output layers and *~/test/example_input.raw* is the path of the input, then the input list file format for the same is as follows:

```
#outputlayer1 outputlayer2
~/test/example_input.raw
```

In the first line # is followed by output layer names which are separated by a whitespace. Next line contains the path to input(single input case). You can also add multiple input files, one line per iteration. If there is more than one input per iteration, a whitespace should be used as a delimiter.
General format for input list file is as follows

```
#<output_name>[<space><output_name>]
<input_layer_name>:=<input_layer_path>[<space><input_layer_name>:=<input_layer_path>]
  …
```

You can refer to [snpe-net-run](https://developer.qualcomm.com/sites/default/files/docs/snpe/tools.html#tools_snpe-net-run) documentation for more information.

Comment: I am so sorry for late responding to you. I just figure out the issues happened with my network. The network has two output layers, but some how when executed, it only got the result for the last layer. I try to set multiple layers when creating network, but it got the error "one or more layers is missing". Do you have any idea to debug it?. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the link to the model (or model summary) you're using, so that I could try for helping you. Also please mention whether you're using snpe-net-run or C++ native code to run the network.

Comment: I finally figure it out. I have taken the wrong output name from the model. Thank you so much and have a great time!

Comment: This critical detail is eminently *unclear* from the linked documentation. Too bad. Guess Qualcomm isn't set up to keep a keen focus on good documentation.